# Entity Framework exception with dynamic query after upgraded to version 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have an application using EF. Originally it was working but when EF is upgraded to 6 one of the dynamic query has started throwing exception. This is what the commandText becomes:

```
SELECT VALUE q FROM SELECT 
[Extent1].[column1] AS [column1], 
[Extent1].[column2] AS [column2], 
[Extent1].[column3] AS [column3]
FROM (SELECT 
[viewPPS].[column1] AS [column1], 
[viewPPS].[column2] AS [column2], 
[viewPPS].[column3] AS [column3]
FROM [dbo].[viewPPS] AS [viewPPS]) AS [Extent1] as q 

var result = pqb.RunQueryQ();
```

It gives exception "The query syntax is not valid. Near keyword 'SELECT', line 1, column 21"

When I update this string commandText becomes:

```
SELECT q.* FROM (SELECT 
[Extent1].[column1] AS [column1], 
[Extent1].[column2] AS [column2], 
[Extent1].[column3] AS [column3]
FROM (SELECT TOP 10
[viewPPS].[column1] AS [column1], 
[viewPPS].[column2] AS [column2], 
[viewPPS].[column3] AS [column3]
FROM [dbo].[viewPPS] AS [viewPPS]) AS [Extent1]) as q
```

But still the error remains the same. What should be the correct syntax for the query?

This is the code that is used to build the query:

```
ParameterQueryBuilder<viewPPS> pqb =
new ParameterQueryBuilder<viewPPS>(context);
string aliasName = "q";

pqb.AddSelect("SELECT VALUE " + aliasName + " FROM " + context.viewPPS.Sql +
" as " + aliasName + " where ", aliasName);
```

ParameterQueryBuilder.cs:

```
public class ParameterQueryBuilder<TEntity> : ParameterQueryBuilder where TEntity : class
{
public ParameterQueryBuilder(DbContext context)
: base(context)
{
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> RunQuery()
{
return base.RunQuery<TEntity>();
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> RunQueryQ()
{
return base.RunQueryQ<TEntity>();
}
}
```

Comment: What is `ParameterQueryBuilder`?  It's not part of EF.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it is a custom class to build dynamic query. It has helper methods to add where clause comparison etc. Once the query is built it is executed using its method "RunQueryQ()" which is included in the code above.

Comment: So EF is not involved, and you are generating a dynamic SQL query with a syntax error.  Are you asking about why those queries are invalid?

Comment: The class is creating the query that I included in my question. Is there any syntax error in it because obviously the first query isn't correct but the second one does execute correctly in SQL Sever MS. This is weird as event after the correct query the method RunQuery() on the object is throwing exception.

Comment: There's just no enough here to know.  If you try to extract a short, complete repro you'll probably find the bug.  If not, post it in your question.

Comment: Sure. I'll come with more findings. Thanks.